# How can we read the smart contracts deployed on the relay chain parachain

Tags: parachain, explorer

Is there a similar feature to etherscan where codes are human readable? Or solcscan where contracts are in bytecodes? I can't seem to find any explorer.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the bytecode/wasm of the contracts in Polkadot.js explorer from chain state. For the wasm contracts, it is at `contracts.codeStorage()` and for EVM contracts `evm.accountCodes()`

As for contract verification, I think only Polkaholic currently supports that for wasm contracts. Here is one [example](https://polkaholic.io/wasmcode/0xee0911882a19ef3eab3d9501f22a70fb3c768e67aba1f6b1b36eee51d51a5956#overview)